# Can we create a new lead record when a custom object record is created?

Tags: visualforce, trigger, community, lead-conversion

My requirement is to create a lead record when a custom object's record is created.I have created all custom fields as on the other custom object so that all data will be copied respectively.
Any idea how can I implement this requirement.Any comment will be helpful..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AfterInsert trigger on your Custom Object or create a new Process using Process Builder that runs AfterInsert to create the records by duplicating the fields onto a Lead and inserting the new Lead record. Either should work for you. It depends on which method you're most comfortable using. I recommend you visit [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules) and go through the modules there if you don't know how to do either of those.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful explaination..Actually I have same fields in lead as in my custom object around 100 custom fields,and I wanted to replicate the whole record custom object's converted  into a lead record.I think trigger would be the best approach for this requirement.

Comment: I'm pleased you found my answer helpful. I'd agree that a trigger would be the best choice. BTW, the code in the answer you accepted isn't even close to what you'd want to use for your trigger. It doesn't even include a for loop to iterate on trigger.new. Again, go through the Trailhead module on Apex Triggers to help you get started if you've never written one and feel free to post your code in a new question or edit this one for reopening if you have problems with it (no code is why it was closed).

Comment: In process builder I m not able create the Lead beceaus its getting error when I assigned the record type Id of my custom object to the lead record type Id.

Comment: Vicky, you need to edit you question to have it reopened or ask a new one if you need further help. You've currently checked @E.Samoylova answer to your question as accepted & will want to uncheck it if your question hasn't been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any apex code via triggers when new custom record be inserted. Also you can create new record. For example:

```
trigger TriggerName on YouCustomObject__c (after insert){
   list<lead>NewLeads = new list<lead>();

   for(YourCustomObject__c Record:trigger.new){
      Lead l = new Lead(LastName = Record.LastName);
      NewLeads.add(l);
   {

   insert NewLeads;

}
```

You can find inserted custom record in Trigger.new as shown in code above.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE. Your code was incomplete. I have edited your post to show how a correctly bulkified trigger would work. It also would have exceeded the DML limit of 150 records/execution context by inserting records to the database individually rather than saving them to a list to insert all at one time.